# JRE Architecture Dependencies (Running on MIPS)

Tags: jvm, embedded, mips, java

OpenJDK currently does not have support for a JRE on MIPS processors (there's a [port in progress](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/mips-port/), but who knows how long that will take).

I'm trying to understand how the JRE works, and what is standing in the way of using OpenJDK on our embedded system running Linux on a MIPS processor. If I have a custom JVM that is capable of running on MIPS designed to work with OpenJDK (in this case, I'm referring to [JamVM 2.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jamvm/files/jamvm/JamVM%202.0.0/)), is there anything else preventing the JRE from running on the MIPS board? Are any other parts of the JRE platform-dependent?

My understanding is that the JRE is (mostly) composed of two units: the virtual machine, which abstracts the hardware and which is platform-dependent, and the collection of Java libraries which run on the virtual machine and which are not platform-dependent.

To be clear, my questions is: aside from the JVM, is any part of the Java Runtime Environment platform-dependent?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: @Durandal i guess i let it get lost in what may be unnecessary context. i've clarified. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"aside from the JVM, is any part of the Java Runtime Environment platform-dependent?"*

That depends on where you place the boundary where the VM ends and the JRE begins. I would consider memory management and code execution as 'the VM', everything more specific part of the JRE.

Thats means every binding to the operating system, be it I/O, Graphics etc. is part of the JRE. Thus the JRE has many platform dependent parts; you usually just don't notice them because your code uses their abstractions (e.g. File, Socket, Window).

So when you say "a port to MIPS" it doesn't mean anything without specifying an OS (ok, your link says Linux); a VM ported to a processor architecture by itself does not make a working java environment. It also requires a port of the native parts of the JRE that allow the java program to actually communicate with things outside the VM; thats where the OS platform comes in.

Since Linux is already supported for x64, the MIPS port should be able to reuse most of the JRE to platform bindings from that.